# Unable to open file (file read failed: time = Sun Aug 23 12:19:51 2020...) in Google Colab

Tags: python, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am training a neural network for image segmentation purpose in Google Colab.

The training code are:

```
 print('Training')
 batch_size = 8
 nb_epoch = 5
 mcp_save = ModelCheckpoint('weight_isic18', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')
 reduce_lr_loss = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=7, verbose=1, epsilon=1e-4, mode='min')
 history = model.fit(tr_data,tr_mask,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=nb_epoch,
          shuffle=True,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(val_data, val_mask), callbacks=[mcp_save, reduce_lr_loss] )
 print('Trained model saved')
 with open('hist_isic18', 'wb') as file_pi:
    pickle.dump(history.history, file_pi)
```

The training process goes smoothly and the weights are saved here:

[image]

The error arises here while loading the weights:

```
model.load_weights('weight_isic18')
```

As:

[image]

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load a model from a directory. Note that the command .load_weights() expects a .h5 file extension, and certainly not a directory.

I think you are looking for this:
`model = tf.saved_model.load(path)`